# Setting coordinate transformation GRID

Tags: qgis, distance, coordinate-system

Does anyone know how to set a coordinate transformation in QGIS so I can measure the distances in meters or kilometers?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure in meters, switch the **project** CRS to a projection that uses metres, like the UTM zone of your part of the world.

The layers can remain in the original CRS (something that SAGA presumably does not offer).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go into "project proprties/general" and check that "Canvas units (CRS transformation: ON/OFF)" is set to meters

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should re-save again  your data (right click on the layer,save as).. this time make sure you change the crs which has distance unit (e.g wgs 84 world mercator - meter units). This new layer should have new distance unit. You can check again whether you already use the right crs through metadata (you can also use qgis browser)

Comment: World mercator has meters as units, but theses are true meters only at the equator. For real distances, take UTM or what is used in your country.